# Why is my IOCompetionCallback never executed on my IO completion port?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

Minimal reproducible example:

Interop.cs

```
public static class Interop
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateIoCompletionPort(
        [In] IntPtr fileHandle,
        [In] IntPtr existingCompletionPort,
        [In] UInt32 completionKey,
        [In] UInt32 numberOfConcurrentThreads);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern UInt32 GetLastError();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static unsafe extern bool GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
        [In] IntPtr completionPort,
        [Out] out UInt32 ptrBytesTransferred,
        [Out] out UInt32 ptrCompletionKey,
        [Out] NativeOverlapped** lpOverlapped,
        [In] UInt32 dwMilliseconds);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
        [In] string fileName,
        [In] UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
        [In] UInt32 dwShareMode,
        [In] IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
        [In] UInt32 dwCreationDisposition,
        [In] UInt32 dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        [In] IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static unsafe extern bool ReadFile(
        [In] IntPtr hFile,
        [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
        [In] uint maxBytesToRead,
        [Out] out UInt32 bytesActuallyRead,
        [In] NativeOverlapped* lpOverlapped);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PostQueuedCompletionStatus(
        [In] IntPtr completionPort,
        [In] UInt32 bytesTrasferred,
        [In] UInt32 completionKey,
        [In] IntPtr lpOverlapped);
}
```

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create completion port
        var completionPortHandle = Interop.CreateIoCompletionPort(new IntPtr(-1), IntPtr.Zero, 0,  0);

        ThreadLogger.Log("Completion port handle: {0}", completionPortHandle);

        var completionPortThread = new Thread(() => new IOCompletionWorker().Start(completionPortHandle))
        {
            IsBackground = true
        };
        completionPortThread.Start();

        const uint Flags = 128 | (uint)1 << 30;

        var fileHandle = Interop.CreateFile("test.txt", (uint)1 << 31, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 3,
            /*FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED */ Flags,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        ThreadLogger.Log("File handle: {0}", fileHandle);

        Interop.CreateIoCompletionPort(
            fileHandle,
            completionPortHandle,
            (uint)fileHandle.ToInt64(), 
            0);

        ThreadLogger.Log("Associated file handle with completion port");

        var readBuffer = new byte[1024];

        uint bytesRead;

        var overlapped = new Overlapped 
        {
            AsyncResult = new FileReadAsyncResult()
            {
                ReadCallback = (bytesCount, buffer) =>
                    {
                        var contentRead = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, (int)bytesCount);
                        ThreadLogger.Log(contentRead);
                    },
                Buffer = readBuffer
            } 
        };

        NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped = overlapped.UnsafePack((uint errorCode, uint numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) =>
        {
            ThreadLogger.Log("Why am I not getting printed?");
        }, readBuffer);

        ThreadLogger.Log("Before read in main thread");

        Interop.ReadFile(fileHandle, readBuffer, (uint)readBuffer.Length, out bytesRead, nativeOverlapped);

        ThreadLogger.Log("After read in main thread");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

FileReadAsyncResult.cs

```
class FileReadAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
{
    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle { get; private set; }

    public object AsyncState { get; private set; }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously { get; private set; }

    public Action<uint, byte[]> ReadCallback { get; set; }

    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
}
```

IOCompletionWorker.cs

```
public class IOCompletionWorker
{ 
    public unsafe void Start(IntPtr completionPort)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            uint bytesRead;
            uint completionKey;
            NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped;

            ThreadLogger.Log("About to get queued completion status on {0}", completionPort);

            var result = Interop.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
                completionPort, 
                out bytesRead,
                out completionKey,
                &nativeOverlapped, 
                uint.MaxValue);

            var overlapped = Overlapped.Unpack(nativeOverlapped);

            if (result)
            {
                var asyncResult = ((FileReadAsyncResult)overlapped.AsyncResult);
                asyncResult.ReadCallback(bytesRead, asyncResult.Buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                ThreadLogger.Log(Interop.GetLastError().ToString());
            }

            Overlapped.Free(nativeOverlapped);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware that if I use `Threadpool.BindHandle` with the corresponding file handle, my callback will be ran - but I'm trying to learn why it's not being executed when it is being registered on my own IOCP which a thread is waiting for completion packages. (Furthermore, the Thread Pool won't know how to handle my custom AsyncResult - the callback there won't get executed.)

Comment: Your CreateIoCompletionPort PInvoke looks wrong. The third argument is ULONG_PTR which should be pointer sized and not UInt32.

Comment: Also how about checking for erorr codes from the API calls? If you want to learn you should first check which method returns an error.

Comment: @AloisKraus no error is being returned anywhere. This is code that has been copied over from [here](https://github.com/dschenkelman/async-io-talk/tree/master/src/IOCompletionPorts). I'm only curious as to why the callback does not end up getting executed. It does get executed when you use `ThreadPool.BindHandle`, but then my custom `FileReadAsyncResult.ReadCallback` won't end up getting executed there.

Comment: @AloisKraus I only added the part of providing an `IOCompletionCallback` to `overlapped.UnsafePack` (instead of being `null`). That's the only difference between the original source code, and the one shown here.

Comment: Your sample works when I run it under .NET 4.8. Where do you run it? I get "Hello world using I/O completion ports!" which is what you expect?

Comment: @AloisKraus The message `Why am I not getting printed?` never ends up getting printed.  It's being ran under .NET 4.5

Comment: The IO Completion Callback is a service of the Threadpool. If you do IO Completion ports all by yourself you do not get this callback. See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/vm/comthreadpool.cpp#:~:text=FCIMPL1(FC_BOOL_RET%2C%20ThreadPoolNative%3A%3ACorBindIoCompletionCallback,OUT%20errCode)%3B

Comment: @AloisKraus The documentation states the same thing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.iocompletioncallback?view=net-5.0), so I'm guessing it really is so. To quote what is being said: `"Receives the error code, number of bytes, and overlapped value type when an I/O operation completes on the thread pool."` Do you know from where exactly that code gets executed on the C# level? I've tried digging down reference source to find the entry point, but couldn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235823/discussion-between-alois-kraus-and-spiritbob).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IO Completion Ports work by creating a completion port, binding it to a file handle and then spin up n IO completion port threads which wait for GetQueuedCompletionStatus to return in this blocking call.

The callback you did mention in your code is not part of the IO Completion port infrastructure. It is a service of the .NET Threadpool where you can call ThreadPool.BindHandle(SafeHandle osHandle) which calls you back when for this handle an IO completion has completed.

But if you do everything on your own then the .NET Threadpool service will not be available to you.
The calling call stack is

```
IOCompletionPort.Sample!IOCompletionPort.Sample.Program+<>c.<Main>b__0_0(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x45[c:\Source\async-io-talk\src\IOCompletionPorts\IOCompletionPort.Sample\Program.cs @ 63]
mscorlib!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x84
clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4e
clr!DispatchCallSimple+0x67
clr!BindIoCompletionCallBack_Worker+0xee
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x40
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x4c
clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+0x2f
clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStubEx+0xb9
clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStub+0x9
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CompletionPortThreadStart+0x604
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x8b
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

The method BindIoCompletionCallbackStub is called on another thread when the IO completion did complete

```
FCIMPL1(FC_BOOL_RET, ThreadPoolNative::CorPostQueuedCompletionStatus, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    FCALL_CONTRACT;

    OVERLAPPEDDATAREF   overlapped = ObjectToOVERLAPPEDDATAREF(OverlappedDataObject::GetOverlapped(lpOverlapped));

    BOOL res = FALSE;

    HELPER_METHOD_FRAME_BEGIN_RET_1(overlapped); // Eventually calls BEGIN_SO_INTOLERANT_CODE_NOTHROW

    // OS doesn't signal handle, so do it here
    overlapped->Internal = 0;

    
    
    res = ThreadpoolMgr::PostQueuedCompletionStatus(lpOverlapped, 
        BindIoCompletionCallbackStub);
```

this is called by

```
ThreadPoolNative::CorPostQueuedCompletionStatus, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
ThreadpoolMgr::CallbackForContinueDrainageOfCompletionPortQueue
```

to execute the IO completion callbacks some time after one or several IO completions have finished. Since you handle everything on your own there is no one calling ThreadpoolMgr::CallbackForContinueDrainageOfCompletionPortQueue to notify your completed IO completion initiated read request.

Comment: I've been terrible busy, still need to get to what we discussed in chat. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: No problem it was an interesting question and I could finally learn more about IO completion ports.